# Auth0 login automatically

Tags: angular, auth0

I've created a new app and I want to use Auth0 for login.

My question is how I can redirect automatically to auth0 login if I'm not logged in yet (without using the Login button from their example)?

I have tried to inject **auth** service in **app.module** and verify if I'm logged in, but it fails because I've entered into an infinite loop.

I think that I have to wait somehow for auth0 to read from storage and only after this to verify if I'm logged in or not.

Comment: Have you tried guards in angular? Here is a resource https://codeburst.io/using-angular-route-guard-for-securing-routes-eabf5b86b4d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with the Auth0 Community and I wanted to reach out and share with you a very recently updated Auth0 Angular Quickstart that can be fantastic to check against your application to make sure everything is setup as we would recommend.

To answer your specific question, I would leverage the `handleAuthCallback()` to check to see if the necessary query parameters (code and state) are present. If they aren't there you can then force a login.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using

1. And using the auth0 angular SDK's inbuilt AuthGuard
2. Or/And using the auth0 provided login page with callback URL
3. Or facing auth.isAuthenticated$ is always false issue in your custom canActivate logic

Try setting the **'Application Type'** to **'Single Page Application'** in auth0 application properties page if you have not already.
[image]